# Need to Integrate multiple table with multiple conditions in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in details page that has `des_id`,
I need to get all the users by the details `des_id` and if they have Role staff.

```
$asignTo=Contracts::find($id)
   ->where('contracts.id',$id)
   ->join('users','contracts.condesid','users.des_id')
   ->join('role_user',function($join){
      $join->on('role_user.role_id', 3);
   })
   ->select('users.*')
   ->get();
```

That doesn't work gives me :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'on
>   clause' (SQL: select `users`.* from `contracts` inner join `users` on
>   `contracts`.`condesid` = `users`.`des_id` inner join `role_user` on
>   `role_user`.`role_id` = `3` where `contracts`.`id` = 8)

but if I used the below code, it gives me all users with role staff only without `des_id.`

```
 $staff = [];
 $users_list =User::all();
 foreach ($users_list as $item){
    if($item->hasRole('staff')){
       $staff[] = $item;
    }
 }
```

Blade:

```
<select class="form-control custom-select-value" name="assigto" required="required">
   <option value="">Select User </option>
      @foreach($asignTo as $user)
         <option value="{{$user->id}}"> {{$user->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: What package are you using for role based permissions?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an error please explain what you get.

Comment: @Petay87 I use Zizaco/entrust

Comment: @dparoli gives me :  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.* from `contracts` inner join `users` on `contracts`.`condesid` = `users`.`des_id` inner join `role_user` on `role_user`.`role_id` = `3` where `contracts`.`id` = 8)

Comment: According to the documentation you should be able to add withRole('staff') to the query.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error there. A question on SO is not olny for solving your coding problem but mostly for others with similar issues.

Comment: please provide **role_user**, **contracts** and **user** table details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your datalayout, and `des_id` and `condesid` are connected:

```
users
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | des_id |
+----+------+--------+

role_user
+---------+---------+
| role_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+

contracts
+----+----------+
| id | condesid |
+----+----------+
```

To retrieve user records filtered on a contract and role ID, the desired query might look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users U
JOIN contracts C ON C.condesid = U.des_id AND C.id = 2
JOIN role_user RU ON RU.user_id = U.id AND RU.role_id = 2
```

When translated to a Query Builder statement:

```
$users = User::select('U.*')
    ->from('users AS U')
    ->join('contracts AS C', 'C.condesid', 'U.des_id')
    ->join('role_user AS RU', 'RU.user_id', 'U.id')
    ->where('RU.role_id', 3)
    ->where('C.id', 8)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much I try it now

Comment: Working Amazing Thank you so much :)