# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::hasRole does not exist. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I use Zizaco/entrust roles for my laravel project, I want to use a dropdown list for users by destination id, and the user has role staff.
the error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::hasRole does not
>   exist.

```
public function show($id)
{
$users_list = User::all();
        $asiTo=Contracts::find($id)
        ->where('contracts.id',$id)
        ->join('users','contracts.condesid','users.des_id')
        ->join('roles','users.id',$users_list->hasRole('staff'))
        ->select('users.*')
        ->get();
return view('admin.contracts.show', compact('asiTo'));
}
```

user calss

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, EntrustUserTrait;
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Role class

```
class Role extends EntrustRole
{
    public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }
}
```

Blade:

```
 <select class="form-control custom-select-value" name="assigto" required="required">
 <option value="">Select User </option>
          @foreach($asiTo as $user)
          <option value="{{$user->id}}"> {{$user->name}}</option>
           @endforeach

   </select>
```

Comment: Where is your query ending? There is no `;`.

Comment: Can you explain what this code does in more detail?

Comment: @Jerodev Sorry I update the question

Comment: This question is closely related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687598/need-to-integrate-multiple-table-with-multiple-conditions-in-laravel) of the same user.

Comment: @JorisJ1 yes this is my question also I don't find resolution yet

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `hasRole()` method through the join. You only access this method only if you have added the `EntrustUserTrait` trait to the related model.

Take a closer look at [the example](https://github.com/zizaco/entrust#user) of zizaco/entrust package, the `User` model used the `EntrustUserTrait` trait after that you can access the `roles(), hasRole()` etc.

To access the `hasRole()`, please set up the **Eloquent Relationship**.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: thank you for your comment, I make the relations and can't use hasrole as in `->join('roles',function($join){
            $join->where(User::hasRole('staff'));
        })`

Answer (score 1):

When you run `User::all()` you get an Eloquent collection returned as opposed to an instance of the model. The `hasRole` method is on the model, which is why you are getting the error.

The `entrust` package has a query scope you can use so that you can get all users with a specific role. To do this you can change your code to something like this:

```php
$users_list = User::withRole('staff')->get();
```

That should then return you only those users who have the role of `staff`.

Comment: thank you for your answer could you tell me how to integrate this code with `join` code

Answer (score 0):

Please join table before use where()

Comment: I try to use `$users_list = User::withRole('staff')
        ->join('contracts','contracts.id',$id)
        ->join('users','contracts.condesid','users.des_id')
        ->select('users.*')
        ->get();` but not working

Comment: you can use  `$users_list = User::join('contracts','contracts.id','=',$id) ->join('users','contracts.condesid','users.des_id') ->select('users.*','contracts.*') where('role_col','staff')->get();`

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'users' (SQL: select `users`.* from `users` inner join `contracts` on `contracts`.`id` = `11` inner join `users` on `contracts`.`condesid` = `users`.`des_id` where `role_col` = staff)`

Comment: can you share model  and function

Comment: I update the question

Comment: okay ill check your question

Comment: I already told you please join table and use another query it will work sure.